# regex for ignoring hostname

Tags: regex

I'm trying to ignore the hostname part of a web address and only keep the path.

For example:

```
http://bar.foooo.com/path1/path2/path3
```

currently I have the following regex:

```
\\bhttp\\b)*(\\bhttps\\b)*(\\b[\\w']{1,2}\\b)*(\\bwww\\b)*(\\bco\\b)*(\\buk\\b)*(\\bcom\\b)*(\\borg\\b)*[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+|[\\w\\d']{20,}|\\b\\w*\\d\\w*", " "));
```

that turns that link to:

```
bar foooo path1 path2 path3
```

but I want to also exclude bar and foooo in other words ignore [http://bar.foooo.com/]

Comment: Your regex is malformed, and you should specify the language used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
^https?:\/\/[^\/]\/(.*)$
```

Which will ignore the starting http://....../ (or https://....../) and will only returns the path

Comment: It needs an extra quantifier

    ^https?:\/\/[^\/]+?\/(.*)$

Answer (score 0):

```
^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/(.+)$
```

Should work.